# I get errors when trying to answer the challenge

Tags: plsql

Create a block containing a variable that can hold a date value (for a billing date), a variable that can hold a character string (for a last name), and a variable that can hold a numeric value (for a credit balance). For variable names, follow the naming conventions introduced in this chapter. Initialize the date variable to the value October 21, 2012 and the numeric variable to 1,000. In the executable (BEGIN) section of the block, assign the character variable’s value as Brown, and include statements to display the value of each variable.

How do i declare and assign a date variable?

Answer (score 0):

> How do i declare and assign a date variable?

Like this:

```
v_billing_date date := date '2021-10-21';
```

I used date literal; you could have used `TO_DATE` function, e.g.

```
v_billing_date date := to_date('21.10.2021', 'dd.mm.yyyy');
```

Just don't rely on implicit conversion and use string instead of date, hoping that Oracle will correctly convert it to a valid date value.

```
SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> declare
  2    v_billing_date    date           := date '2021-10-21';
  3    v_last_name       varchar2(20);
  4    v_credit_balance  number         := 1000;
  5  begin
  6    v_last_name := 'Brown';
  7
  8    dbms_output.put_line(v_last_name);
  9    dbms_output.put_line(to_char(v_credit_balance));
 10    dbms_output.put_line(to_char(v_billing_date, 'dd.mm.yyyy'));
 11  end;
 12  /
Brown
1000
21.10.2021

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```